# List of motor vehicle work (car or motorcycle) that requires licensed mechanic when performed by a for-profit business in Ontario?

Tags: business, motor-vehicle

When I retire, I'd like to open up my own garage, but don't want the overhead and stress of having to hire a licensed mechanic, and don't want to get certified myself. I know there are certain things that can be performed for profit without a license, but where can I find a concise list so that I can determine whether a business built around that would be something I would want to do? For example, I believe suspension and air conditioning fall under the licensed category, and oil changes fall under un-licensed (think of all the teenagers working at Jiffy Lube).

Comment: Related post (dated 2016) https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14762/is-it-illegal-to-repair-vehicles-in-ontario-without-a-mechanics-license

Comment: I don’t know the details of Ontario law but generally trade licensed work must be under the supervision of a licensee , not necessarily performed by the licensee. That covers your Jiffy Lube teenagers - one licensee supervisor, many unlicensed workers.

Comment: When I looked into a Jiffy Lube franchise in the past, one of the FAQ's mentioned that no licensed mechanic was required to be on staff due to the nature of the services offered.

Comment: @RockApe Thanks, but I saw that before posting. Nobody answered the question, and I didn't have enough to points to comment to ask for clarification.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the law states a vague general "standard" (e.g. "mechanical or electrical or bodywork repairs of motor vehicles for profit or for another requires a license") than it is that there is a detailed list of included and exempt activities, although there might be some safe harbor exceptions that don't count.